# Setting a background image not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with getting the background to display in the emulator. It will show up on main.xml though and there is no errors. So the screen just comes up black here is my main.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:background = "@drawable/clearskies">

   <TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/hello" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and yes I do have my image in the drawable folder and the spelling is correct and the image is a .png

Can anyone see what im doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: the xml is working fine for me. clean the project. try with a newly created emulator?

Comment: provide your source code so that we can help you otherwise as @WinMyoHtet says xml is fine

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are setting the layout file.

in onCreate(), use,

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you see your image in background of graphical Layout of your xml if yes then it must problem with your java file otherwise it problem with your image or drawable something else...